The space of bounded smooth functions with rapidly decaying derivatives
Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded smooth function such that all of its partial derivatives are rapidly decaying. That is, for any nonzero $n$-dimensional multi-index $\alpha$, $D^\alpha f$ is a Schwartz function.
Any Schwartz function satisfies this definition. Moreover, $x \to \exp\Bigl(i \exp(-\lVert x \rVert^2)\Bigr)$ is not a Schwartz function but still satisfies this definition.
Let $M$ be the space of such $f$'s. Then, I guess that we can give a countable family of seminorms on this $M$ by
\begin{equation}
\lVert f \rVert_{\sup} \text{ and } \lVert f \rVert_{\alpha, \beta}  \text{ where } \alpha (\neq 0),\beta \text{ are multi-indices}
\end{equation}
Here, $\lVert f \rVert_{\alpha, \beta}:=\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \bigl \lvert x^\beta (D^\alpha f)(x) \bigr \rvert$ just like semi-norms for Schwartz functions as in this link.
Now, my question is

Does $M$ become a nuclear Frechet space with this semi-norms, just like the Schwartz space?

I have not seen such a function space before, but I guess it it is not too different from the Schwartz space. However, I would like to check if I am right.
Could anyone please help me?

This is just the space $S(\mathbb R^n)\oplus\mathbb R$ when $n\ge2$. When $n=1$ this is $S(\mathbb R)\oplus\mathbb R^2$, so yes.
Indeed, $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)$ always exist as for every $|x_1|,|x_2|>R$ you can find a $\gamma:[0,\pi R]\to\mathbb R^n$ connecting $x_1,x_2$ such that $|\dot\gamma|\le1$ and $|\gamma(t)|\ge R$, and then
$$
|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\le\|f\|_{1,k}\pi R\cdot R^{-k}\xrightarrow{R\to\infty}0.
$$
Now $f(x)-\lim f$ is a function that vanishes at infinite. And for every $|\theta|=1$,
$$|f(R\theta)-\lim f|\le\int_R^\infty|\nabla f(t\theta)\cdot\theta|dt\le\|f\|_{1,k}\int_R^\infty t^{-k}dt\lesssim_kR^{1-k}.$$
So it is rapidly decay, hence combining with the derivative bounds, it is a Schwartz function.
When $n=1$ we cannot connect dots from either side, so $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)$ can be two values. Take bump function $\chi$ such that $\chi|_{x<-1}\equiv0$ and $\chi|_{x>1}\equiv1$. Then
$$
f(x)-f(-\infty)-(f(+\infty)-f(-\infty))\chi(x)
$$ is a Schwartz function, since by the same argument above it is rapidly decay at $\pm\infty$.

Thank you for your answer. Could you explain a bit more on how $M$ is identified with $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n) \oplus \mathbb{R}$ for $n \geq 2$ and $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}) \oplus \mathbb{R}^2$?

@Isaac which part do you want more details?

@Isaac I don't think your edit in my answer is that correct. I only says f-lim f vanishes at infinite, the argument haven't proved it rapidly decay yet.

I would like to ask for more details on how to identify $M$ with $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n) \oplus \mathbb{R}$ and how to show that $f - \lim f$ is rapidly decaying. I appreciate any help or hint!
